# What makes this question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

A couple of days ago, I voted to close [this qestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867416/are-there-differences-between-cli-and-tui) as off-topic.

It seems I'm still the only one who think it's off-topic, probably the question has been removed from the review-queue by another user.

The question is, as far as I see, about terminology and not related with Ubuntu, so my question is:

What makes this question on-topic?

Comment: It is terminology that is used by people who use these interfaces on Ubuntu, so is related to Ubuntu. I don't see how that is off topic, it doesn't ask what cli and tui means it asks what is the difference between the two.

Comment: The purpose of my question is to improve my voting behaviour. I had the impression, that the terms `tui` and `cli` and the difference between them are nothing special for Ubuntu but valid for all operating systems, of course also for Ubuntu. I think that's the point, close vote retracted.

Comment: *the difference between them are nothing special for Ubuntu:* Same goes with shell scripting. However that's still on-topic.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes, perfect example...

Comment: Relevant discussion: [Are "not only Ubuntu-specific" questions on-topic?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> nothing special for Ubuntu

Ask Ubuntu allows *relevant to Ubuntu*, not just *restricted to Ubuntu*.

We've been through a few rounds of fireworks on Meta about this before, but ultimately, you'd go mad —and drive the rest of us that way too— if you tried to only allow questions that only worked on Ubuntu (and tried to push everything to a more generic or specific site).

There's always a better pigeon hole for things. In practice, all you need do is work out if Ask Ubuntu is good enough that that person is going to get a satisfactory answer. In many questions like this, the answer is a resounding yes.

Comment: When your answer arrived, I retracted my close vote already, Mark's comment helped a lot to. Thanks for your feedback, I was thinking about all that and came to the same conclusion.